# Can't verify if Android wear 2.0 app updated on playstore

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

So I have an app with a phone and a wear module. I recently updated the package with the same version codes for both watch and phone and uploaded my mobile-release.apk to play store for alpha testing. I finally got the update on my phone, but my watch app has not been updated. few more detailed information to help you diagnose the problem:

1. The watch was off for a long time but now I have it fully charged.
2. it is not connected to Wi-Fi due to security reasons of this area, but it is well connected to my phone for sure.
3. I checked the installed version of the app on the watch and it is one version older than the latest update.
4. I went to play store on watch and checked if the app needs a manual update, it doesn't say anything and just says "installed"

So,
Does the watch have to be connected to Wi-Fi to get app updates?

How do I check if my wear module is also updated correctly (I know that it is nested in the mobile-release)?

my package names and version codes are all exactly the same. Am I missing something? My watch is running Wear 2.0 (LG Urbane)

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced similar issues with builds in the alpha channel not being installed (or even discoverable) on the wearable. Two things you can do are:

1. Make sure that you have a Google account on the wearable that has
   access to the alpha channel. (Might sound stupid, but trust me, it
   happens.)
2. Promote to beta

We've never experienced these issues with builds in the beta channel, so hopefully this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The first one is verified. it took a while but installed. Can't promote to beta unless I have started my research study :-)